# {button}.onclick to change textContent

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, global-variables, onclicklistener

I'm trying make simple game "**Rock Paper Scissors"**. At this moment I got stuck in changing value of Global Variable. Situation: (for ex.) *Click* => [Rock]. I have to store this into Global Variable's ("**playerMove**").

```
const rock = document.createElement('button');
/*
*/
let playerMove;
playerMove = '';
```

I arleady try

```
rock.onclick = function() {
   playerMove = 'Rock'; // Test in function..
}
```

but Its only work in function (Yea, we all know global variable doesn't work that way so..). I may be able to fix that problem soon but at this moment my mind can't think any better than this :|, I want help to find any good resource about this to (how) change textContent / Value of element by clicking on button.

*Sorry for my bad English..*

Comment: The title mentions `textContent`, but you don't use that anywhere in the question. If you want to display the move to the user, use `someElement.innerText = playerMove;`

Comment: My bad, I use in code but I didn't mention in the title (I comment down below how it works rn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HTMLButtonElement.addEventListener()` to listen for "click" events, and then do whatever you want to, a simple demo

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('test');
const container = document.getElementById('val');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.textContent = 'works'
})
```

```html
<div id="val">test</div>
<button id="test">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the playerMove variable you could use a function that set that value.

```
document.createElement('button');
const rock = document.querySelector('button');

let playerMove = ''
const updateMove = (move) => {
  playerMove = move;
}

rock.onclick = () => {
  updateMove('Rock');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rock = document.getElementById('button');
console.log(rock)
let playerMove;
playerMove = '';
rock.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
     playerMove =e.target.innerHTML;
     console.log(playerMove);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html>  
     <head>    
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
           <title>  Aide</title> 
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
     </head>    
    <body>       
        <header>
        <button id="button">Rock</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>    
</body>
 </html>
```

**strong text**

*This code works perfectly.
it takes the text that the button contains.
I think your mistake is that you didn't declare that the button you created a js is a child of body.*

Answer (score 0):

Ty guys

Well, I will explain lil more about what playerMove was doing..

```
playerText.textContent = playerMove;
```

so I simple was trying to change playerMove but after I see [AnanthDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15925814/ananthdev) answer >>

```
function playerMove(element, move) {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
        playerText.textContent = move;
    })
}

playerMove(rock, 'Rock');
playerMove(scissors, 'Scissors');
playerMove(paper, 'Paper');
```